# How to run Alfresco 5.2.c (EA) with Solr 6.3?

Tags: solr, alfresco, solr6

I want to run [Alfresco Community Edition 201611 EA](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6467-alfresco-community-edition-201611-ea-release-notes) with Solr 6.3 using [Solr 6 Integration](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6471-alfresco-community-edition-file-list-201611-ea#jive_content_id_Solr_6_Integration).

The `alfresco-search-services-1.0.a\README.MD` instruction:

> **Install & Run**
>
> To run, unzip then 
>   `solr/bin/solr start`

... unfortunately it isn't enough ;(

Can anyone guide me how to reconfigure both `Solr 6.3` and `Alfresco 5.2EA` to make they work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document published today (20-12-2016) by [Axel Faust](https://community.alfresco.com/people/afaust) on [community.alfresco.com](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6556-using-solr-6-in-alfresco-community-edition-52-201612-ga):

> [Using SOLR 6 in Alfresco Community Edition 5.2 (201612 GA)](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6556-using-solr-6-in-alfresco-community-edition-52-201612-ga)
>
> ... Installation ...